# Web Based Survey Sampling method

Tags: sampling, sample-size, sample, survey-sampling, internet

I am doing a web based research with target audience as general public. I am a student and so due to limited resource, i basically did snowball sampling. I approached all those whom i knew, some agreed to participate and i forwarded the questionnaire to my contacts and the to contact's contact. 
450 questionnaires have been filled. My aim is to get to 500. 
When i computed the sample size using the formula, it came out to be 387. 
Now, I am thinking, should i consider all the 500 samples or should I randomly select 387 out of 500. What would be a better sampling method? And if i randomly select 387 would that count as simple random sampling?
P.S I a beginner at this so please need your help.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to study, exactly? How did you forward the survey to all your contact's contacts?  There are likely better ways to go about your research than a "snowball sample," which is a very specific technique typically reserved for hard-to-reach populations.  It also produces biased results.  You mentioned that you computed "the sample size using the formula." What formula are you using and/or where did you obtain this formula?  What is your reasoning for using only 387 out of 500 responses?

Comment: I am trying to study the usage of antibiotics among the general public and their awareness regarding proper use.

Comment: https://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm                                                                                           I used this to calculate the sample size needed using 5 % confidence interval and 95% confidence level

Comment: I approached people i knew and asked them to participate. Also asked them to forward the questionnaire to their relatives and friends.

Comment: I basically want to have frequencies and percentages, and also compare self medication practice  based on gender, education and income.